# Using lasio.read() , read commented out lines(#) and preserve those lines while writing to Las

Tags: python-3.x, las

I want to read a LAS file, make some changes in well, curve, parameter and other sections and write them back to LAS files.

But the issue is during writing operation all commented out lines are getting removed as they were not read by lasio at first place.

Is there some way in lasio to read commented out lines?

Answer (score 0):

As per the lasio docs [here](https://lasio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data-section.html#ignoring-commented-out-lines) you can set a flag to change the default functionality of ignoring commented out lines using `remove_data_line_filter='#'` as an argument in the read function

Comment: Thanks for the response but remove_data_line_filter='#' applies only to the data section and my query is for header sections like well,curve, parameter.